# Getting Quake 1 to work

Tags: quake

I have an old copy of Quake 1 I bought years ago as part of an id Anthology, but it won't install on my Windows 10 PC - Whenever I try to run `setup.exe` I get a message saying "This app can't run on your PC".

I have downloaded Quake 1 along with Joe Quake from the internet, and it works great.  However, I can only access the free episode of the game, the other three episodes of the game are locked off and asking for a purchase of the game.

How can I make this new copy of Quake realize that I have bought it already so I can play the rest of the game?

Comment: When was the anthology released? Are you trying to install right off the CD?
If there is a CD key associated with the copy you have, there's a chance you can use it on a platform like Steam. Otherwise, you need instructions on how to deal with your specific copy.

Comment: I figured this out, I used winrar to get at the pak1 file and then put that with my working copy of quake and everything worked out fine

Comment: You can answer your own question with this solution.  However, you should know that the original Quake had its list of valid CD keys stored on the disc in the code.  If you obtain any CD key for Quake, it will very likely unlock any demo copy you have.